# Update iptables using ansible iptables module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to update iptables in my linux box, I am trying to use iptables modules for this below command. Can you please help me .

```
"- iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,830 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT"
```

I am trying to update but I am getting an error, Can you please help me.

```
ERROR:
{
"_ansible_parsed": true,
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"protocol": "tcp",
"chain": "INPUT",
"cstate": "NEW",
"jump": "ACCEPT",
"destination_port": 80,
"match": "multiport"
}
},
"changed": false,
"_ansible_no_log": false,
"msg": "Unsupported parameters for (iptables) module: cstate Supported parameters include: action, chain, comment, ctstate, destination, destination_port, flush, fragment, goto, icmp_type, in_interface, ip_version, jump, limit, limit_burst, log_prefix, match, out_interface, policy, protocol, reject_with, rule_num, set_counters, set_dscp_mark, set_dscp_mark_class, source, source_port, state, syn, table, tcp_flags, to_destination, to_ports, to_source, uid_owner"
}
```

Comment: As the error message says, cstate doesn't support parameter "NEW". Did you mean ctstate?

Comment: cstate can accepts "NEW"

Comment: You're correct. Ctstate accepts the value "NEW", but you've misspelled `ctstate` as `cstate`. Hence the error.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? Or do you have any additional problems?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible gives you an error, because you've specified a parameter called `cstate`. Iptables module doesn't have that parameter. Infact you've probably misspelled `ctstate`, which is an existing parameter in iptables module. Correct this and the error will disappear.